# What explains these bizarre result when scraping a website with lxml and python?

Tags: python, html, debugging, web-scraping

As the title says, I'm just messing around and practicing my python skills so im scraping this website, or attempting too. Everything has been going well until now when I am trying to scrape an html table. The url I am attempting to scrape is:

https://farm.ewg.org/persondetail.php?custnumber=A09875645&summlevel=whois&dbtouse=2001

I am trying to get in my code each of the values in the table including names and percentages. I right click the first two values I want from the first column and click inspect. Then I observe their xpaths are:

```
//*[@id="main_content_area"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a
//*[@id="main_content_area"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/a
```

Ok I think, easy enough these are just the first columns in the 2nd and 3rd row. So I set up the following python code to try and retrieve these values:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
testerURL = 'https://farm.ewg.org/persondetail.php?custnumber=A09875645&summlevel=whois&dbtouse=2001'
testerPage = requests.get(testerURL)
testerTree = html.fromstring(testerPage.content)

testerRow1 = testerTree.xpath('//*[@id="main_content_area"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a/text()')
testerRow2 = testerTree.xpath('//*[@id="main_content_area"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/a/text()')
print(testerRow1)
print(testerRow2)
```

This returns the following:

```
['Leitrim Farms, Inc']

[]
```

How strange I think, it prints the first one but the second one in testerRow2 appears to be empty. I then throw in 3 more print statements into my python code:

```
print(len(testerTree.xpath('//*[@id="main_content_area"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr')))
print(testerTree.xpath('//*[@id="main_content_area"]/div/div/table/tbody/text()'))
print(len(testerTree.xpath('//*[@id="main_content_area"]/div/div/table/tbody/text()')))
```

Which return:

```
2
['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']
17
```

Ok - this is very weird. It seems to say the table only has two rows - which is wrong- but explains why i couldnt get the value in the third row. Checking the table though seems to return the correct number of rows, 17, but they are all empty strings with the line break character in them - WTF?!

Any ideas? I have used this process to scrape tables before with python but have never seen this issue. Is there something super obvious im missing? i've spent 4 hours bashing my head against my keyboard :O

The following:

```
len(testerTree.xpath('//*[@id="main_content_area"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr'))
```

Really should return 17 rows, not 2 and the fact that is returning 2 is nuking my head.

Update: A commenter suggested maybe the information was not part of the html on site but was instead loaded via js, and that is why I am unable to get the info from the html. I do not think this is correct though as when I manually inspect the website the data appears hard coded in html and not loaded via js.

Comment: `the table only has two rows - which is wrong` - how do you know it's wrong? If you're comparing in the web browser that's not the same thing. The browser runs javascript, `requests` doesn't.

Comment: well when I copy the Xpaths from the rows of interest from the website one of them, as i said above, is in the third row. I can do this all the way down to the 17th entry and it says it is in the 17th row.

Comment: Yes, but the web browser has run javascript to populate the table. If you save the html you've downloaded with python and view it in a web browser it won't have the data.

Comment: Interesting, I dont get why the first row from the table is in the actual html code while the rest is loaded in javascript. Also if thats the case i dont get why when I read the html code for the page these names are all hard coded in html as far as i can tell and not loaded via js.

Comment: "Ours is not to reason why."